# visual basic argument null exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, null, arguments

I am about to admit defeat on this, I'm fairly new to VB and I am sure there is something quite basic I've managed to miss,

My problem with the following code is when the Button3_Click function is executed a "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item" exception arises at run-time, if I forget to include the ".Name" on this line "ListBox2.Items.Add(test.Name)" then stuff still gets vomited out to the listbox so assuming there's something there,

any help?

Regards
Dan

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles
    Button3.Click

    Dim test As comdevice

    Dim usbcoms() As comdevice = FindComs()

    For Each test In usbcoms
        ListBox2.Items.Add(test.Name)
    Next


End Sub    


Private Function FindComs() As comdevice()
    Dim USBClass As New System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_PNPEntity")
    Dim USBCollection As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection =   
    USBClass.GetInstances()
    Dim USB As System.Management.ManagementObject
    Dim temp() As comdevice
    Dim n As Integer
    n = 0

    For Each USB In USBCollection
        If USB("Name").ToString().Contains("P") Then
            n += 1
        End If
    Next USB
    ReDim temp(n)

    n = 0
    For Each USB In USBCollection
        If USB("Name").ToString().Contains("COM") Then
            temp(n).Name = USB("Name").ToString()
            temp(n).DeviceID = USB("DeviceID").ToString()
        End If
    Next


    Return temp
End Function

Private Structure comdevice
    Public Name As String   ' This employee's given name.
    Public DeviceID As String   ' This employee's family name.
End Structure
```

Comment: Where is `ListBox2` declared? Is it ever getting assigned to?

Comment: Its up in the main form, it takes data in any way than this case

Comment: Or not at all, possibly. If `ListBox2` doesn't get assigned or if it gets assigned a `null`, you would get this error. Same with the `Name` property of a `usbcom` - it may be `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems lies in the FindComs method.
The first loop search the USBCollection for devices that contains the letter `P` and you count them.
In the second loop, after dimensioning the return array with the number of devices found you try to fill this array with devices that contains the string `COM`, of course there is no relation between devices with `COM` and `P` in their name. You end up with an array bigger than the effective number of devices with `COM` in their name.

When the array returns, you add every slot of the array, but you have slots with NULL values and thus the error.
You can fix the problem dimensioning the array only for the devices with `COM` in their names

```
For Each USB In USBCollection
    If USB("Name").ToString().Contains("COM") Then
        n += 1
    End If
Next USB
ReDim temp(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Oded's comment is the most likely cause of this failure.

An easy test is to set the `Name` property to some default string, like "test" in your `comdevice` class.

That way, the `Name` property will never be null and you can see if it ever gets changed.